# Avoid scrollbar on popup - position: fixed

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a Sidebar that open when I click on a button, and I set its position to `fixed` so that it can take the entire screen like this (I use TailwindCSS) :

```
return (
    <div className="fixed z-40 flex left-0 top-0 h-screen w-screen">

      // this div set a gray color to the entire screen
      <div className="w-full bg-zinc-500 fade-in"></div>

      // this div is 600px wide on right of screen
      <div className="bg-stone-100 w-600 bg-white">
        <div className="p-8">
          [ MY FORM ]
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
```

I set it `fixed` because it is an under component, and I need it to overcome the header and another sidebar that are called on top of the App.

Here is the structure of my App :

```
function App() {
    const AppLayout = () => (
        <>
            <Header />
            <div className="flex">
                <Sidebar />
                <Outlet />
                // the sidebar I'm trying to fix is in Outlet
            </div>
        </>
    );
```

**Problem is :** when I open my sidebar (below), it takes all screen, but the scroll bar scrolls the page that is UNDER this sidebar, not the content IN my sidebar.

Any idea how I can disable the scroll bar for the page, and enable one for my fixed component ?

PS : here is a sandbox that reproduce the problem [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-frog-dxwfjj?file=/src/pages/MyPage.js:514-523) (as you can see, i can scroll the page but not the popup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @iamhuynq mentioned in the comments, setting up an overflow-auto and a useEffect solve the problem. Thank you !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can disable page scroll by set overflow hidden for body when you open sidebar and remove when you close. Also add overflow auto on sidebar

```
useEffect(() => {
    const openSideBar = () => {
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    };
    const closeSideBar = () => {
        document.body.style.overflow = '';
    };
    if (isOpenSidebar) openSideBar()
    else closeSideBar()
    return () => closeSideBar();
}, [isOpenSidebar]);
```

Comment: Yes, but this disable sidebar globaly. I cant scroll in my component Sidebar that is now opened :/

Comment: @Joh can you try to add `overflow-auto` to your sidebar

Comment: I added a height of 600px and overflow-y-auto but I have 2 scrollbars now. One for the form inside the side bar, and one for the page behind the sidebar :/

Comment: @Joh if you add overflow hidden to body, it can not have scrollbar for the behind page :/

Comment: can you provide codesandbox example?

Comment: @Joh I've created [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-lamport-ubx1vl?file=/src/pages/MyPage.js). Can you check?

Comment: It works ! You just added the useEffect and overflow auto ? @iamhuynq

Comment: yes, i added useeffect and overflow auto for sidebar